# How to prove that $f(x_n)n \rightarrow 1$?

Tags: limits, continuity

Define $x_n = \inf \{ x \ | \ f(x) \le \frac{1}{n} \}$ where $f(x) = \frac{\log x}{x}$.

I want to prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)n = 1$.

How do I show this? It seems obvious but I don't know how to formalize this.

Comment: If it seems obvious, there's something that's guiding your intuition. What is it?

Comment: $f(x)$ is increasing on $(0,1]$, so one assumes your $x_n$ would be the supremum not the infimum

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want $x > e$,
so $f(x)$ is decreasing.

Since $f(x)$ is decreasing and continuous,
$f(x_n) = \dfrac1{n}
$
so
$nf(x_n) = 1$.

Note that this applies
to any continuous decreasing function.

Comment: You are using the fact that $f(x)$ is continuous. What if it wasn't? For example, say $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x}$ where $g(x)/\log x \rightarrow 1$, so $g(x)$ is still similar to $\log x$ in its growth, but we don't know if $g$ is continuous... What can we say then?

Comment: That is another question. Feel free to ask it as a separate question.